# Suppose $f$ is nonnegative and integrable on some measure space $(X, \mathcal{A}, \nu)$. Show $\lim_{t\to+\infty}t \cdot \nu(f \geq t) = 0$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Suppose $f$ is nonnegative and integrable on some measure space $(X, \mathcal{A}, \nu)$. Show $\lim_{t\to+\infty}t \cdot \nu(f \geq t) = 0$.

My first attempt is to use Fubini to get

$$ \int_X f \, d\nu = \int_0^\infty \nu( f\geq t ) \, dt \,\, . $$
Here $(f \geq t) = \big\{ x\in X \,:\, f(x) \geq t \big\}$.

It is clear that  $\lim_{t\to+\infty} \nu(f \geq t) = 0$. And intuitively, the function $t\longmapsto \nu(f \geq t)$ is a decreasing integrable function, its tail may behave like $t^{-\beta}$ with $\beta > 1$, in this case the desired result follows.

More work is needed and any comment is highly appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$t \cdot \nu(f \geq t) = \int_{\{f \geq t\}} t \, d\nu \leq \int_{\{f \geq t\}} f \, d\nu$$

Comment: Thanks. The proof can be done by applying dominated convergence then.

Comment: @Chival Yes - or monotone convergence (since $f$ is non-negative).